# Property 'document' does not exist on type 'CollectionReference' function cloud

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

i am trying to update a document in firestore when test function is triggered as shown below

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'


admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.test = functions.firestore.document('test/{id}').onCreate(event => {
    admin.firestore().collection("testcollection").document(data.truckId)
    })
```

but this line of code is not working

```
admin.firestore().collection("testcollection").document()
```

its giving me error that document function does not exist

**EDIT**

I am using the following code

```
  admin.firestore().doc(`anothercollection/${data.id}`)
    .get().then((result)=>{
   });
```

its working fine but when use the following command  to deploy the function

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

I am getting the following error

```
Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create@firestore.googleapis.com (test)
✔  functions[test(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.

Functions deploy had errors. To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`collection()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore#collection) returns `firebase.firestore.CollectionReference` and inside the class [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference) there is no method called `document()`, that's why you get an error.

Comment: i understand that but how to access a document in order to update some of its values?

Comment: try doc() method https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc. Also there is `onUpdate()` trigger instead of `onCreate()`

Comment: its working but i am getting another error now ,i edited the question

Comment: Remove $ from data.id

Comment: the $ is just a way to write a variable in a string ,its not related to the error

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1:**

1. Import
2. Create a reference to the document under collection 'test'
3. Set the value

   ```
   import {  doc, setDoc, updateDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
   const docRef = doc(this.firestore, 'test', id);
   setDoc(docRef, { name: name }, { merge: true });
   ```

**OPTION 2:**

```
updateDoc(docRef, { company: company });
```

*The different between them is that the first option, if document does not exist will create it*